# Angular Toggle Button not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to implement toggle functionality in angular so when button is toggled different text is displayed. Error is thrown in my code. Any help? Code below.

HTML

```html
<tr>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>
    <button class="btn-primary text-dark bg-white">
      {{isChecked ? 'ACCESS' : 'NO ACCESS'}}
    </button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="form-check form-switch">
      <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="checkbox"
        (changed)="isChecked=$event"
        checked
      />
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

TS

```js
isChecked: boolean;
```

Comment: My bad. Made a mistake. Didn't copy entire html. Guess I was very tired. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like below

HTML

```
<tr>
<td>Otto</td>
<td><button class="btn-primary text-dark bg-white">{{isChecked ? 'ACCESS' : 'NO ACCESS'}}</button></td>
<td>
   <div class="form-check form-switch">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" (change)="getValue()">
   </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

TS

```
  isChecked: boolean = true;

  getValue() {
    this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
  }
```

Comment: Hi. The toggle seems to affect the value the other rows. When I toggle for the first row, it displays "ACCESS", but the other rows button also display "ACCESS" even when not toggled. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: have u try using different name variable for every toggle you use, so its not affect one another?

Comment: I did but seems it had no effect. HTML is 3 of the 'tr'  part of the question I posted. Only difference is different names for the td. Any suggestion would be welcome. Thanks.